# My bitcoin transaction has not yet gone through. (4 days)

Tags: bitcoin-core

I have googled this problem and everyone just keep saying "be patient it will get through sooner or later". Well it has now been 4 days and it still says 0/6 confirmations. I did not send it with a miners fee which is why it's not instant but it feels like 4 days is a long time. I'm using bitcoin-qt wallet on a ubuntu 12.04 computer if that makes any difference. Also when I go to blockchain.info and try to search for my transaction I cant find it. I have right clicked on my transaction and tried to search for everything thats in details but I still cant find my transaction.
Should I just wait and see if its going to get through?

I have read that you can double spend and then send this new one with a miners fee. I have tried to read up about this but I'm quite worried because its a lot of money that I'm sending and I don't want to do anything wrong.

Comment: Last it was measured, the average time to get a zero fee transaction (that would normally require one) into the blockchain was around a week.

Answer (score 1):

Has the blockchain fully downloaded yet?
If you haven't totally downloaded the chain yet, you wont see any money you have received.
Do you have to create a raw transaction?
https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Raw_Transactions

If you are really struggling, send me an email. Maybe we can do SSH or remote desktop, and I can save your bitcoins.
If you run "bitcoind listtransactions" in a terminal and send me the output, I might be able to get you better instructions.

Comment: Yes my blockchain is fully downloaded. What exact details of my transaction can I search for on blockchain.info?

Comment: Please don't include email addresses in posts. If you must, put the email address in your user profile.

Answer (score 0):

Search blockchain.info for the address you are sending the coins from.

If you cannot see your transaction on blockchain,info, then it is not on the network and will not confirm.

Comment: I am searching from the address that I sent the coins from and I cant see my transaction at blockchain.info. You have any idea what to do here? Still standing at 0/6 and I have my blockchain updated

Answer (score 0):

How much money did you send and how long have you owned it? How many bytes was the transaction? Your transaction will only be accepted as no-fee if the weighted average of input value times input age per byte exceeds a threshold (roughly equal to one BTC x day per 250 bytes).